# I'm attempting to convert my function parameters to a key within a hash but i am stuck

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to convert my function perimeters to a key within a hash.

I want my to_roman function to take whatever parameters i give it and convert that to roman numerals. Here is waht i have so far:

```
def to_roman(num)

  result = ""
  numerals = {
    I: 1,
    V: 5,
    X: 10,
    L: 50,
    C: 100,
    D: 500,
    M: 1000
  }

  numerals.each do |roman, numbers|
    if num % numbers == 0
      result << roman.to_s
    end
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Michael Berkowski There is no English word perameter.

Comment: @sawa :) There sure isn't. That started as "perimeter" and that's a good example of "distracted editing"

Answer (score 1):

I've reversed the hash because you want to first calculate how many time the highest number goes into num and keep working from there.

```
def to_roman(num) 
    result = ""
    numerals = { 'M'=> 1000, 'CM' => 900, 'D'=> 500, 'CD'=> 400, 'C'=> 100, 'XC'=>90, 'L'=> 50, 'XL'=>40, 'X'=> 10, 'IX'=> 9, 'V'=> 5, 'IV'=> 4, 'I'=> 1  }
    numerals.each do |roman, numbers|
        result << (roman *(num/numbers))
        num-= num/numbers*numbers
    end
    result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Following function will convert Arabic digits to Roman

```
def to_roman(num) 
  result = ''
  roman_mappings = { 'M'=> 1000, 'CM' => 900, 'D'=> 500, 'CD' => 400, 'C'=> 100, 'XC' => 90, 'L'=> 50, 'XL' => 40, 'X'=> 10, 'IX' => 9, 'V'=> 5, 'IV' => 4, 'I'=> 1  }
  roman_mappings.each do |roman, number|
    result << roman * (num / number)
    num = num % number
  end
  result
end
```

Following are some conversion examples:

```
2.1.2 :148 > to_roman(1)
 => "I" 
2.1.2 :149 > to_roman(2)
 => "II" 
2.1.2 :150 > to_roman(4)
 => "IV" 
2.1.2 :151 > to_roman(5)
 => "V" 
2.1.2 :152 > to_roman(6)
 => "VI" 
2.1.2 :153 > to_roman(9)
 => "IX" 
2.1.2 :154 > to_roman(10)
 => "X" 
2.1.2 :155 > to_roman(14)
 => "XIV" 
2.1.2 :156 > to_roman(40)
 => "XL" 
2.1.2 :157 > to_roman(49)
 => "XLIX" 
2.1.2 :158 > to_roman(50)
 => "L" 
2.1.2 :159 > to_roman(595)
 => "DXCV" 
2.1.2 :160 > to_roman(999)
 => "CMXCIX" 
2.1.2 :161 > to_roman(2001)
 => "MMI"
```

Comment: Why your answer looks so similar like [this one one the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26644379/1106814)? Do you know that you can either make small improvements by editing (read the rules shown while editing) or at least give credit if you really need a separate answer.